# What's the exact meaning of Unique Events metric of Google Analytics in SQL terms?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm experiencing with Google Analytics and I thought I found a way to implement my needs. But to my surprise, after waiting for a day, the results are not as I expected.

Here's my Javascript code to log some events. This first one is written in `head` tag:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-1', {
  'cookieDomain': 'none' //Since I'm testing from my localhost
});
ga('set', 'screenName', 'Testing GA');
ga('set', 'dataSource', 'localhost-spa');
ga('set', 'userId', 'mehran');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Then I have the following in a button's onclick:

```
var i = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
ga('send', 'event', {
    'eventCategory': 'cat1',
    'eventAction': 'action_1',
    'eventLabel': 'Action 1',
    'eventValue': 1,
    'dimension1': 'dim_' + i
});
```

Yesterday I clicked on the button for couple of times, perhaps around 200. And I designed a customized report with the following configurations:

```
Metrics: Total Events, Unique Events
Dimensions: dimention1
Filters: Include + Event Action + Exact = action_1
```

And as I said I waited for one day, the results were:

```
# ----------------------------------------
# All Web Site Data
# Events
# 20150401-20150501
# ----------------------------------------

dimension1, Total Events, Unique Events
dim_2    24  2
dim_3    20  2
dim_5    20  2
dim_4    18  2
dim_8    17  1
dim_1    16  2
dim_10   16  2
dim_9    16  2
dim_6    13  2
dim_7    12  2
         181 21
```

Why does the `Unique Events` column have 2 in it? How is an event considered unique? I was expecting all the values within `Unique Event` to be 1!

**[UPDATE]**

I created another report and that puzzles me as well. Here's its definition:

```
Metrics: Total Events, Unique Events
Dimensions: Event Action
Filters: Include + Event Action + Exact = action_1
```

And it outputs:

```
# ----------------------------------------
# All Web Site Data
# Events
# 20150401-20150501
# ----------------------------------------

Event Action, Total Events, Unique Events
action_1    181    2
            181    2
```

I was hoping to see 10 in the Unique Events column! What's going on? Is it me or Google who needs to change?

[UPDATE]

Now that I think of it, considering the second report's results, the first report translate to:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT eventValue) FROM ... GROUP BY date, dimension1 HAVING `Event Action` = 'action_1'
```

Yet it doesn't explain the value of 2, instead of 1! Even though I was hoping the filters are translated into a condition within `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

What I suspect might be happening here is that your series of "Event-generating clicks" might have spanned across 2 Sessions.

As per the Google Analytics' definitions (visible in the Report tooltips):
[image: Events Report]

> - **Total Events**: Total Events is the number of times events occurred.
> - **Unique Events**: The number of times during a date range that a session contained the specific dimension or combination of dimensions.

For more information, it might be worth reading this article, which gives a more details explanation of Unique Events: http://www.analyticsedge.com/2014/09/misunderstood-metrics-unique-events/

Comment: What if I don't care for sessions? Is there anyway I can tell GA not to consider sessions? The fact is I don't care who's sending the log, I want to be able to be in charge of all the data. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I think the best you could do in regards to that is to change the Session duration in Analytics (Property Settings > Tracking Info > Session Settings). Although the minimum duration is 1 minute and the maximum duration is 4 hours, so depending on your needs, that might not entirely fit your requirements.